# c++ template with partially fixed argument list

Tags: c++, templates, c++-templates

Consider a case like the following:

```
template<typename T>
class A { ... };

template<typename T, typename DataType = std::vector<A<T>>>
class B {
  ....
  DataType data;
  ...
}
```

In my case the `DataType` type can be any std "container", but it must always be specialized with type A. The use of A should be transparent from outside class B, however in the definition of B without the default type for `DataType` one should explicitly specify e.g. `B<int, std::deque<A<int>>`. I'd like to remove this possibility and achieve something like:

```
template<typename T, typename container = std::vector>
class B{
  using DataType = container<A<T>>;
  ...
}
```

so that I would specialize B like `B<int, std::vector>`.
Of course it cannot be exactly like this because `container` in this case should a complete type and then must be specialized. Is there a way to achieve this with c++14?

Comment: `template <typename...> typename Container = std::vector`. But I question whether this is a good idea, because what if someone wants to pass a container with a custom allocator? And so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter), e.g.

```
template<typename T, template <typename...> typename container = std::vector>
class B {
  using DataType = container<A<T>>;
  ...
};
```

Then use it like `B<int>` (i.e. `B<int, std::vector>`) or `B<int, std::deque>`.

Comment: How is the `template<typename ...>` syntax called so I can look up for documentation?

Comment: @NicolaLissandrini See [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).